# conditional checking of xml sub elements while validating with XSD

Tags: xml, validation, xslt, xsd

I have an XML like below.  I want conditional checking.
ie

1. When `<datatype>` is int `<subelement>` should be mandatory.
2. When `<datatype>` is bool `<subelemnt>` is optional.

note: I am using xml 1.0.

This is allowed:

```
    <element>
      <name>
      abc
      </name>
      <datatype>
      int 
      </datatype>
      <subelement>
      </subelement>
    </element>
```

This is allowed:

```
    <element>
      <name>
      abc
      </name>
      <datatype>
      bool 
      </datatype>
      <subelement>
      </subelement>
    </element>
```

This is not allowed allowed:

```
    <element>
      <name>
      abc
      </name>
      <datatype>
      int 
      </datatype>
 
    </element>
```

here is the basic xsd

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="element">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="datatype"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="subelement"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Is it possible to do it? Would be great if there is an example.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This needs XSD 1.1, with assertions:

```
<xs:assert test="if (normalize-space(datatype)='int') 
                 then exists(subelement) 
                 else true()"/>
```

It's not possible with XSD 1.0.

Comment: I see, Thank you very much.